# BeanLocator is null for servlet context

Tags: java, liferay, javabeans, context.xml

Continually get this error on one server but not the other. 
Both servers have the same code deployed to it and in comparing the context.xml and the applicationevn.xml they are both insync. where else do I even look to start solving this bean error

> 11:40:04,180 ERROR [tomcat-http--24][PortletBeanLocatorUtil:42]
>   BeanLocator is null for servlet context message-manager-portlet
>   11:40:04,183 ERROR [tomcat-http--24][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has
>   not been set for servlet context message-manager-portlet
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortletBeanLocatorUtil.java:46)
>           at com.fm.fmconnect.mm.service.MessageManagerReportTypeLocalServiceUtil.getService(MessageManagerReportTypeLocalServiceUtil.java:349)
>           at com.fm.fmconnect.mm.service.MessageManagerReportTypeLocalServiceUtil.findSellerServicerCounts(MessageManagerReportTypeLocalServiceUtil.java:331)
>           at com.fm.fmconnect.mm.action.CommonAction.updateSellerServicerIds(CommonAction.java:234)
>           at com.fm.fmconnect.mm.action.CommonAction.setSellerServicerValues(CommonAction.java:159)
>           at com.fm.fmconnect.mm.portlet.controller.MessageManagerController.doView(MessageManagerController.java:148)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:235)
>           at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:314)
>           at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)
>           at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
>           at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
>           at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:117)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)

Comment: Try redeploying the portlet.

Answer (score 1):

### What portal version are you running?

Have you tried deleting all of the files generated by service builder (except the three modifiable impl files), running your ant `clean` target, and building/deploying?

To be more explicit I would delete the following files.

1. /WEB-INF/lib/message-manager-portlet-service.jar
2. /WEB-INF/service (entire folder)
3. /WEB-INF/sql/indexes.sql
4. /WEB-INF/sql/tables.sql
5. /WEB-INF/sql/sequences.sql
6. /WEB-INF/src/META-INF (everything in this folder assuming no XML modifications were made)

Then run the following ant targets
   1. clean
   2. build-services
   3. compile
   4. deploy

Then start the server.